# How to get the height of shop catalog image in WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce

I want to get the height of the shop catalog image size which I can use in some files for styling purpose. I think this is the option name `shop_catalog_image_size` which I call like `get_option('shop_catalog_image_size');`

But I want only the height of the image and not the dimension. Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Height is dependent of the hard cropping / dimension options in woocommerce settings > Products > display > Product Image (depending too on original picture format: Landscape or Portrait)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the WooCommerce Display options from DB's wp_options table like this:

```
$ShopCatalogImageSizeOption = get_option('shop_catalog_image_size');
```

It returns with an array, which contains width and height to, so the answer is:

```
ShopCatalogImageHeight = $ShopCatalogImageSizeOption['height'];
```